# GIRA eNet and a new light fixture/bulb

Tags: lighting, smart-switch, the-netherlands

A year ago, we bought a house, and, with the house, we were handed a small, three-button clicker. Something like this (but with no labels on the buttons) [image: The Clicker]

The first button turns on/off a series of lights in the kitchen. The second button turns on/off several lights in the garden. And the third button causes a click sound in the ceiling above the dining area. So, I gathered it's a yet-unused button.

When I inspected the hole with the clicking sound, I saw there was this device. [image: The Device] [image: The Device]

I was wondering where should I look to hook up a new lightbulb or a new standing lamp, etc. (or if there are any suitable light fixtures for it. I have no idea where to look for.)

Comment: Is that actuator actually wired to anything?  I think the wires are supposed to be inserted into the N/L/A1 holes, so it looks like a "no."

Comment: So, should something like a receiver/transmitter be wired to those holes?

Comment: IDK, maybe your German is better than mine. https://partner.gira.de/data3/54231310.pdf